# c# query to txt

Tags: c#, sql

I was reading the example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

And wanted to do a test reading that select and writing it into a file:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\stupidtest\customers.txt", reader.ReadToEnd());
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

But i can't because 'SqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'ReadToEnd' and no extension method 'ReadToEnd' accepting a first argument of type 'SqlDataReader' could be found.

So how can i get that simple select into a txt file with an output like this one?

```
dasdgdsgsdg     asgasg    sadgasdgasdg          agdsfg
sdasdgasdgasgg  sdfasdfa  sadfasdfasdgasdgasdg  sadgasgdgda
a               asd       gdgasdg               asdfgghh
```

If i use:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\stupidtest\customers.txt"))
            {
while (reader.HasRows)
            {                       
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    file.WriteLine(reader.GetString());
                }
                reader.NextResult();
            }
```

could i achieve it?

Comment: The reader contains multiple columns over multiple rows possibly comprising multiple types, there is no single textual representation of them all, if you want one you would loop each column in each row building the string manually.

Comment: `ReadToEnd` is defined on `TextReader`, which is the base class of `StreamReader`. A `SqlDataReader` is not a `TextReader` - it is a `DbDataReader`

Comment: @grant, alex, preston: thank you for pointing it out. i edited the question.

Comment: @Malkavian You can use `Sqlcommand cmd = new Sqlcommand("SELECT * from Customers",sqlConnection1);`

Comment: @Malkavian You don't need the line `reader.NextResult();` and you could replace the line `while (reader.HasRows)` with `if(reader != null && reader.HasRows)`

Comment: Always remember put them into `try...catch...finally...` to response to the  exceptions in the `catch` part, close and dispose the SqlObject in `finally` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
static string ReadToEnd(this SqlDataReader rdr){
    StringBuilder MyStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        String line = "";
        for(int i=0;i<rdr.FieldCount;i++)
        {
            line+=rdr.GetString(i)+@"\t";

        }
        MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(line);
    }
    return MyStringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: iirc GetString will throw on a DBNull

Comment: thank you, i will put up a test environment and check it out

Comment: agree with Alex K. need to add IsDBNull check )